# Can I create Dynamic columns (and models) in django?

Tags: python, django, model

I want to create a database of dislike items, but depending on the category of item, it has different columns I'd like to show when all you're looking at is cars.  In fact, I'd like the columns to be dynamic based on the category so we can easily an additional property to cars in the future, and have that column show up now too.

For example:

[image: Table example picture]

But when you filter on car or person, additional rows show up for filtering.

All the examples that I can find about using django models aren't giving me a very clear picture on how I might accomplish this behavior in a clean, simple web interface.

Comment: Are you asking how to model your database, or how to display this to the user?

Comment: I'm starting by asking how I would model this type of data appropriately in django.  Once I understand that, I'll spend a little more time seeing if I can figure out the right way to display it so I know what specific question to ask on that front.

Comment: I'll also need to create views of this data in the database for another tool to use on the backend if that impact how I should be modeling the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for a model describing a "dislike criterion":

```
class DislikeElement(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item) # Item is the model corresponding to your first table
    field_name = models.CharField() # e.g. "Model", "Year born"...
    value = models.CharField() # e.g. "Mustang", "1960"...
```

You would have quite a lot of flexibility in what data you can retrieve. For example, to get for a given item all the dislike elements, you would just have to do something like `item.dislikeelements_set.all()`.

The only problem with this solution is that you would to store in `value` numbers, strings, dates... under the same data type. But maybe that's not an issue for you.

Comment: That would be an issue.  if there are 200 cars in the database, I would need to be able to filter on just cars, then sort them based on the year they were made.

Comment: @JustinJansen I see two solutions: You could add several fields to the model above to describe the value, and use whichever is convenient for your purpose. Or you could create different models: ``DislikeCharElement``, ``DislikeIntElement``... Django does not provide any way to dynamically create database tables as you would like, and that would be a lot of work to implement it yourself.

Comment: So, if I went this route, but it important that numbers be numbers (like the year), what would it look like if some fields are strings, but some others are numbers